# Android: do something when AlertDialog is cancelled

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have an `AlertDialog` that can be cancelled (either by back button or clicking outside the dialog). If the dialog is cancelled I need to undo some changes, so I need to control when it's cancelled.

I tried to create my own subclass of `AlertDialog` to override some functions (I guess I should override `onContextMenuClosed`, I wanted to do some tests to find the correct function).

I created my own Builder extending `AlertDialog.Builder` to create my dialog, and I wanted to override the `create()` function. I checked the `AlertDialog.Builder->create()` code, and it uses the variable `AlertController.AlertParams` P to get some needed data, but that variable is private and I can't access it from my builder, so I can't create my dialog.

How can I control if an `AlertDialog` is cancelled? Using `setCancellable(false)` is not an option, I want the user to be able to cancel it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try setting `setOnCancelListener`:

```
 dialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {    //close the dialog      
        @Override
        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
            //do something
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the onCancelListener in this way:

```
alertDialog.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
            // YOUR CODE HERE

        }
    });
```